# Getting the current complete URL with JavaScript and using it with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, social-networking

I am to implement social network buttons on some one's website. I am hoping to do it as easily as possible AND futureproof so that the customer doesn't need to add anything when he creates a new page. All his pages are HTML (not PHP) so I can't use any PHP. I was thinking of JS and then using jQuery's `.append` to make it all nice and easy, but I was wondering whether there is a better way and/or this method has any flaws? Here is the code:

**HEAD** (scripts):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>$(document).ready(function() {
    var currentURL = window.location; //Get the URL, put it in a variable

    $('#fb').append('<div class=\"fb-like\" data-href=\"' + currentURL + '\" data-send=\"true\" data-width=\"450\" data-show-faces=\"true\" data-font=\"arial\"></div>');
});</script>
```

**BODY**

```
<body>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>
        (function (d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
            js = d.createElement(s);
            js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=177213782346727";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>

    <div id="fb">Test</div>
</body>
```

Any remarks on that? I don't want to fully implement this and then have to change everything all over again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once in a while Google's API Libraries go down for whatever reason.

I think including a fallback method to load jQuery would be welcomed in the head section:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

For the buttons themselves, animating them with open source [jqDock](http://www.wizzud.com/jqdock/examples/) might interest you which is based on JavaScript and jQuery and not CSS3. One of that site's [webpages](http://www.wizzud.com/forums/public-forums-group2/jqdock-forum1/) is using a social-plugin from Wordpress that you might want to look at. It shows a method similar to your DIV's and JS but is different for the FB connection scheme. Perhaps a mashup method is in order.

If jqDock is overkill, there's a lot more nifty Social Button plugins and CSS/Animated [tutorials](http://hoomb.blogspot.de/2012/05/pretty-animated-share-buttons-using.html) to pick from which are direct in what they do.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your fb-like div in #fb, and edit data-href after load :

```
$("#fb-like").data("href",window.location);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I like my script more because then my client only needs to give his HTML structure a div named FB and that's that, whereas yours offers the same basic idea, but it shows more code to the client by which he may get confused. Thanks for the reply though!